# CSS how to force a new div to go under the previous one since the width won't fit

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Assuming I have the following HTML

```
<div className="cards-container">
  <div className="card" />
  <div className="card" />
  <div className="card" />
  <div className="card" />
  <div className="card" />
  <div className="card" />
</div>
```

Now I have 6 Cards. These cards for instance appear on the top of each other in my screen on the left side.

```
Card1
Card2
Card3
Card4
Card5
Card6
```

I'd like to make them appear as follows:

```
Card1 Card2 Card3
Card4 Card5 Card6
```

And if the width of the screen is smaller, it would go like this

```
Card1 Card2
Card3 Card4
Card5 Card6
```

css:

```
.cards-container {
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;

  .card {
     border-radius: 7px;
     height: 228px;
     width: 361px;
     min-width: 361px;
     margin-left: 23px;
     margin-top: 8px;
   }
}
```

I thought about splitting the cards into 2/3 arrays with Javascript based on the screen width then render each row with flex-direction: column; but now sure if that's right.

Something like

```
 const Array1 = [Card1, Card4]
 const Array2 = [Card2, Card5]
 const Array3 = [Card3, Card6]
```

Then add them into 1 array as follows `Arrays = [Array1, Array2, Array3]`

then render them on sparate divs.

Comment: Any reason you are not using any UI libraries like bootstrap, foundation etc?

Comment: @kinglish I guess yes!!! I believe I was missing the flex-wrap: wrap;

Let me poke around more and see if that will do what I really want.

Please submit as an answer if you want so that I can approve.

Comment: @Lukman I haven't done a lot of research, I believe css tricks could be enough..

Comment: You can use the Display Grid property to achieve what you need I believe.

Comment: @ShrishSharma Display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; is all you need.

I missed the flex-wrap property which prevented the trick

Comment: @Ziko that's cool..glad that your problem's fixed ;)